# Load initial data for Select2 having an AJAX URL to load data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 with multiple values in a form which populates its' option data via AJAX.

But in case of form submission, if there's a server-side validation error, I need to show the user the data that they already entered. Therefore, I need to load data to the Select2 keeping the AJAX URL intact.

Anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the code for the form html action, how do you do the form submission ?

Comment: My HTML action is to the same URL.. I use Zend forms (PHP) and do validation using Zend. My intention is to use a hidden field to store the value user enters as JSON, so that the user entered value is available after form submission. Is it clear?